# Struggling with regex to match only two of a character, not three

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match all occurrences of // in a string in a Javascript regex

It can't match /// or /

So far I have `(.*[^\/])\/{2}([^\/].*)`

which is basically "something that isn't /, followed by // followed by something that isn't /"

The approach seems to work apart from when the string I want to match starts with //

This doesn't work:

> //example

This does

> stuff // example

How do I solve this problem?

Edit: A bit more context - I am trying to replace // with !, so I am then using:

```
result = result.replace(myRegex, "$1 ! $2");
```

Comment: Do you only need to match `//` or also the text around it?

Comment: I'm trying to replace all occurrences of // with !

Comment: For simple string operations you should use simple string operations like `String.replace`, not regexes. Matching a (or two) chars qualifies as a simple string operation.

Comment: @nikc: He is using `String.replace`. How would you specify to replace only `//` but not e.g. `///` without regex?

Comment: @Felix: ah, my bad, too much whisky. Missed that `///` (and friends) should be ignored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace two slashes that **either** begin the string or do not follow a slash,
 **and** are followed by anything not a slash or the end of the string.

```
s=s.replace(/(^|[^/])\/{2}([^/]|$)/g,'$1!$2');
```

Comment: @Devbook.co.uk: You must do something wrong, works perfectly for me.

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste fail, that seems to be working thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
/([^/]*)(\/{2})([^/]*)/g
```

e.g.

```
alert("///exam//ple".replace(/([^/]*)(\/{2})([^/]*)/g, "$1$3"));
```

**EDIT**: Updated the expression as per the comment.

<del>/[/]{2}/</del>

e.g:

```
alert("//example".replace(/[/]{2}/, ""));
```

Comment: This will replace part of `"foo///bar"`, which the asker mentioned he didn't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it wouldn't work for `example//` either.

The problem is because you're matching `//` preceded and followed by at least one non-slash character. This can be solved by anchoring the regex, and then you can make the preceding/following text optional:

```
^(.*[^\/])?\/{2}([^\/].*)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [negative lookahead/lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertions:

`(.*)(?<!/)//(?!/)(.*)`

Comment: JavaScript does not support lookbehinds.

Answer (score -1):

This does **not** answer the OP's question about using regex, but since some of the original comments suggested using .replaceAll, since not everyone who reads the question in the future wants to use regex,  since people might mistakenly assume that regex is the only alternative, and since these details cannot be accommodated by submitting a comment, here's a poor man's non-regex approach:

1. Temporarily replace the three contiguous characters with something that would never naturally occur — really important when dealing with user-entered values.
2. Replace the remaining two contiguous characters using .replaceAll().
3. Return the original three contiguous characters.

For instance, let's say you wanted to remove all instances of ".." without affecting occurrences of "...".

```
var cleansedText = $(this).text().toString()
    .replaceAll("...", "☰☸☧")
    .replaceAll("..", "")
    .replaceAll("☰☸☧", "...")
; 
$(this).text(cleansedText);
```

Perhaps not as fast as regex for longer strings, but works great for short ones.